# How to get PDF in byte[] without forming a file?

Tags: java, pdf, stream, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

Below is my code snippet:

```
 try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(PDF_NAME)) {
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(IOUtils.toInputStream(xml, "UTF-8")), res);
        }
    byte[] inputFile = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PDF_NAME));
    String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inputFile);
    InventoryListSnapshot pojo = new InventoryListSnapshot(invList.getInventoryLayoutId(), invList.getProjectId(), invList.getAuthorUsername(), encodedFile);
    repository.save(pojo);
```

It used `xsl-fo` to form PDF in the file. I need to place this PDF encoded by Base64 as BLOB into DB - so I don't use the file itself.

How can I save PDF into DB without forming a file?

Answer (score 0):

You would change this:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(PDF_NAME)
```

to

```
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's works.
The new version is:

```
byte[] pdf;
    try (OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(IOUtils.toInputStream(xml, "UTF-8")), res);
        pdf = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) out).toByteArray();
    }
    String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pdf);
    InventoryListSnapshot pojo = new InventoryListSnapshot(invList.getInventoryLayoutId(), invList.getProjectId(), invList.getAuthorUsername(), encodedFile);
    repository.save(pojo);
```